# Select and replace code from Hackerrank's Codemirror

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

How do I select and replace the code in Hackerrank's Codemirror editor via jquery? I want to automate code submission to Hackerrank challenges (via zombiejs or phantomjs).

I've tried looking this up on Codemirror's documentation and other Stackoverflow answers, but to no avail.

Here is a challenge url: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/solve-me-first